# Nexus IQ to get the EOS details of each library

Tags: maven, dependencies, nexus, nexus-iq

How to find out the particular library is in EOS(End of Support) already? Currently the Nexus IQ Server points out the License or any security vulnerability. Are there any way to get the report where it will show this particular library is End of Life, or End of Support?

Comment: Did you find any output of it. Currently I am looking for it, if you how to fix this please share.

Comment: bump, would like to know as well